# Pyqt5 - Zoom on a QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlabel

I'm trying to apply a zoom example that I've found on this site but it uses a QGraphicsScene and a QGraphicsView while I should use a simple QLabel. This is the code but it does not work. Can I zoom on a Qlabel or is it impossible?
The zoom should work with ctrl++ / ctrl+- shortcut.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel
class GuiZoom(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
   factor = 1.5

   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       super(GuiZoom, self).__init__(parent)

   
       self.setFixedSize(800, 600)

    
       self.lblZoom = QLabel("Facciamo lo zoom")
       self.lblZoom.setStyleSheet("border:10px solid green")
    
       self.setCentralWidget(self.lblZoom)

       QtWidgets.QShortcut(
           QtGui.QKeySequence(QtGui.QKeySequence.ZoomIn),
           self.lblZoom,
           context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut,
           activated=self.zoom_in,
       )

       QtWidgets.QShortcut(
           QtGui.QKeySequence(QtGui.QKeySequence.ZoomOut),
           self.lblZoom,
           context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut,
           activated=self.zoom_out,
       )
   def zoom_in(self):
       scale_tr = QtGui.QTransform()
       scale_tr.scale(GuiZoom.factor, GuiZoom.factor)

       tr = self.lblZoom.transform() * scale_tr
       self.lblZoom.setTransform(tr)

   def zoom_out(self):
       scale_tr = QtGui.QTransform()
       scale_tr.scale(GuiZoom.factor, GuiZoom.factor)

       scale_inverted, invertible = scale_tr.inverted()

      if invertible:
           tr = self.lblZoom.transform() * scale_inverted
           self.lblZoom.setTransform(tr)


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys

   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   ui = GuiZoom()
   ui.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Moreover can you explain me what the last lines of zoom_out functions do? Is this a way to invert the zoom?

Comment: QGraphicsScene's solution is not applicable to QLabel because the latter does not have the setTransform method, change `QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcu` to `QtCore.Qt.WindowShortcut` and you will see that error. Why is it necessary to use QLabel? What advantages do you plan to obtain?

Comment: No, it is not necessary to use QLabel, but I'm learning PyQt so I'm trying to use the element I know. I want to know if a QTransformation could be applied to a QLabel and a zoom examples sounds to me like a good example to study.

Comment: Recommendation: If a class already implements that logic then do not complicate implementing the same logic from scratch. If you want to learn not only do a copy-paste if you do not investigate in the docs, for example QLabel does not have any method that interacts with QTransform: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel-members.html , have you done that research that is also part of learning?

Comment: This is my research, I'm new of qt and I'm trying to understand how these libraries work. I want to understand if qlabel could be used with qtransform, thank you!

Comment: @Nunkij I sincerely hope that with "this is my research" you don't mean "trying something I know very little about and then go on StackOverflow to ask why it doesn't work". You said that QLabel is among the elements you know, but then you tried to do something that is clearly not supported (is `setTransform` in the list of QLabel functions?): you just know about it, you don't know how it works and how to properly use it. "Research" means that if you want to do something on QLabel while it was done on a QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene, then you have to study the documentation about *all of them*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a QGraphicsEffect to scale the QLabel's painting.

Note: The size of the widget is not changed but the painting is scaled.

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ZoomEffect(QtWidgets.QGraphicsEffect):
    factor = 1.5
    _scale = 1.0

    @property
    def scale(self):
        return self._scale

    @scale.setter
    def scale(self, scale):
        self._scale = scale
        self.update()

    def draw(self, painter):
        painter.setRenderHints(
            QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing
            | QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform
            | QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing
        )
        center = self.sourceBoundingRect(QtCore.Qt.DeviceCoordinates).center()

        pixmap, offset = self.sourcePixmap(QtCore.Qt.DeviceCoordinates)
        painter.setWorldTransform(QtGui.QTransform())

        painter.translate(center)
        painter.scale(self.scale, self.scale)
        painter.translate(-center)

        painter.drawPixmap(offset, pixmap)

    def zoom_in(self):
        self.scale *= self.factor

    def zoom_out(self):
        self.scale /= self.factor


class GuiZoom(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GuiZoom, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)

        self.lblZoom = QtWidgets.QLabel("Facciamo lo zoom")
        self.lblZoom.setStyleSheet("border:10px solid green")

        self.zoom_effect = ZoomEffect()
        self.lblZoom.setGraphicsEffect(self.zoom_effect)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.lblZoom)

        QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence(QtGui.QKeySequence.ZoomIn),
            self.lblZoom,
            context=QtCore.Qt.WindowShortcut,
            activated=self.zoom_effect.zoom_in,
        )

        QtWidgets.QShortcut(
            QtGui.QKeySequence(QtGui.QKeySequence.ZoomOut),
            self.lblZoom,
            context=QtCore.Qt.WindowShortcut,
            activated=self.zoom_effect.zoom_out,
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ui = GuiZoom()
    ui.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you! I will test the code soon. 
Can I ask you what is the difference in the note "The size of the widget is not changed but the painting is scaled"?